# Weird order of executing threads in C++

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I've tried to execute first example from [Linux Tutorial Posix Threads](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html).
That's what I have:

```
[alex@Allok c_c++]$ g++ -lpthread from.cpp
from.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
from.cpp:10:22: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
from.cpp:11:22: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
[alex@Allok c_c++]$ ./a.out 
Thread 2 
Thread 1 
Thread 1 returns: 0
Thread 2 returns: 0
```

The problem is that I expected to have the output like the source says:

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 1 returns: 0
Thread 2 returns: 0
```

I don't understand why it happens. Can anyone help me?

```
[alex@Allok c_c++]$ uname -a
Linux Allok 3.3.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 14 10:08:43 UTC 2012 i686 AMD Athlon(tm) II Neo K125 Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Why not? once you're in parallel processing, things can happen in any order they want, unless you take steps to make things happen in a specific order.

Comment: The "Thread 1" and "Thread 2" outputs do not represent the creation of the threads, but the operation of the printf in the thread function. Once you create the threads, it is up to the operating system to decide when the threads get time in the processor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Threads, by definition, are executed asynchronously (it's all at the whim of the OS scheduler).  You can't assume anything about how they execute with respect to one another, unless you explicitly use synchronisation mechanisms.

Comment: And things get even crazier when it comes to printing to the standard output, due to the copious amounts of buffering involved.