# Synchronization in Pthread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I've read about synchronized thread in [Posix threads tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html). They say that function pthread_join is used for waiting thread until it stops. But why doesn't this idea work [in that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364299/weird-order-of-executing-threads-in-c)?

Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a[5];

void* thread(void *params)
{
    cout << "Hello, thread!" << endl;

    cout << "How are you, thread? " << endl;

    cout << "I'm glad to see you, thread! " << endl;
}

void* thread2(void *params)
{
    cout << "Hello, second thread!" << endl;

    cout << "How are you, second thread? " << endl;

    cout << "I'm glad to see you, second thread! " << endl;

//    for (;;);

}

int main()
{
    pthread_t pt1, pt2;

    int iret = pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, thread, NULL);
    int iret2 = pthread_create(&pt2, NULL, thread2, NULL);

    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;

    pthread_join(pt1, NULL);
    cout << "Hello, middle!" << endl;

    pthread_join(pt2, NULL);

    cout << "The END" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is not clear what code you are referring too.

Comment: It must print Thread 1 then Thread 2 because I use pthread_join for Thread 1 before Thread 2. But it works in other way.

Comment: No, it must not print Thread1 and then Thread2. Thats a wrong assumption. As the second comment in your original question correctly states, the `printf` statements do not necessarily reflect the order of thread creation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird order of executing threads in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364299/weird-order-of-executing-threads-in-c)

Comment: Thread execution is non-deterministic. You cannot assume any order of execution.

Comment: ok, in that case I don't understand the purpose of pthread_join. 
"The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate" - the quote from man. And now we see that it doesn't wait in some cases. Depend on OS sheduler.

Comment: @Allok, it always wait for it to terminate. Just in some cases it has already terminated by the time you call join(), so there is nothing to wait for... thread execution starts immediately after you create() it.

Comment: You should really consider reading a book about concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are executed asynchronously, as someone already mentioned in answer to question you linked. Thread execution starts right after you `create()` it. So, at this point:

```
int iret = pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, thread, NULL);
```

`thread()` is already executing in another thread, possibly on another core (but it doesn't really matter). If you add a `for (;;);` in your `main()` right after that, you will still see thread message being printed to console.

You also misunderstood what `join()` does. It waits for thread termination; as your threads don't do any real work, they will (most probably) reach their ends and terminate way before you call `join()` on them. Once again: `join()` doesn't start execution of thread in given place, but waits for it to terminate (or just returns, if it's already terminated).